# What is the impact of specifying or not specifying runtime target in web.config?

Tags: .net, iis, application-pool

I have .NET 4.6.1 installed. The app pool shows 4.0, I know that this is the CLR version.

The web.config file doesn't have any runtime target .net version.

Question 1: Does this mean that the website will run in .net 4.0 or .net 4.6.1?

Question 2: For each of points below, what will happen if I specify the web.config runtime as:

1. 4.0
2. 4.5.1
3. 4.6.1

Answer (score 0):

Question1:

CLR version will not affect the website run in .net4.0 or 4.6. Only the .net version installed on your machine will affect website.
[image]

Question2:

If you have an application and the web.config has `<httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />`, it means the project designed to use .net4.5 runtime assemblies without recompiling existing project assemblies in deployment machine before loading it into memory.

In order to maintain the backward compatibility of the .net version, http runtime was introduced in .net4.5. You can understand it as the first time you specify the .net version in VS and create an application, the target framework of httpruntime is the .net version. But this does not mean that the framework of the project is changed by modifying httpruntime. Modifying the framework of the project needs to be modified in the properties.

Suppose your application is developed using .net4.5. But it uses .net4.7 when running. Then .net will apply the quirk mode, as far as possible to ensure the realization of the function, imitating .net4.5. But if your application is developed by .net 4.6, setting httpruntime to a lower .net version will not help.